# how to fix a section position

Tags: floats

I have sections in my report in latex.

I want to know how can I fix the position of the section in the report.

I have some pictures after the section, but all of them come before the section,

```
\begin{figure}[!htb] 
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[trim=0.5cm 7cm 0cm  6.5cm,clip,scale=.75]{Figures/Conductivity_Result_20C_Fitting.pdf}
        \caption{Conductivity Measurements at 20C}
        \label{fig:Conductivity_Result_20C_Fitting}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}
```

and the section code is:

```
\section{Summary}
```

Comment: Consider adding `\usepackage[section]{placeins}`. More fine-tuning is possible if you look at the documentation for that package.

Comment: To stop a figure coming before the position of the `figure` environment use the  `flafter` package.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- from the docs: "Something you may not like is that, by default, “\FloatBarrier” is very strict, and will (try to) prevent a float from appearing above the start of the current section or below the start of the next section, even though the float is still on the same page as its intended section. Each restriction can be relaxed separately by using the “[above]” and “[below]” package options: “[above]” allows floats to appear above their section, if on the same page; “[below]” allows below."  The original version "acted like it was loaded with the
option “[above]” specified."

Comment: @jon reading documentation! that's cheating:-) I'll delete my comment sorry:-) (although flafter is still probably the package of choice here)

Comment: @jon `NOTE!  The original version of placeins.sty acted like it was loaded
with the option "[above]" specified.` seems like I haven't looked at the documentation since before 2005:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- Hey! Some of us need to cheat just to stay in the race!!  (So keep the comment, so I can point to it in the future.)  A comment about `flafter` is still apropos, too.